# large numbers and float and double in C

Tags: c, matrix, floating-point, double, gpu

I need to deal with very large matrices and/or large numbers and I don't know why 
double result = 2251.000000 * 9488.000000 + 7887.000000 * 8397.000000;
gives me the correct output of 87584627.000000.
Same with int result.

However, if I use float result = 2251.000000f + ... etc,
it gives me 87584624.000000 and I have no idea why!

Can somebody tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: A float only has 23 bits of precision (on most platforms).

Comment: For instance, http://www.vaughns-1-pagers.com/computer/powers-of-2.htm shows that would be a little over 6 decimal digits of precision, while the sum in the question is 8 digits.

Comment: Those are not large numbers - you are well within the range representable by double and float alike. What you are talking about is precision. There are ways to get as high of a precision as you want, but before going there, you need to understand if you actually have an insufficient precision issue, or you just think you do.

Comment: Floating point numbers prove the existence of (*your favorite deity/deities here*) by negation as they are clearly the work of (*your favorite personification of evil here*). Share and enjoy.

Comment: A float does NOT have 23 binary digits of precision, it has 24 (of which one is implicit). This means that the largest integer that may be represented is 2^24 or 16777216 (7+ digits). The next (higher) integer is 24^2+2 or 16777218. The PREVIOUS (LOWER) INTEGER

Comment: An IEEE754 float does NOT have 23 bits of precision, it has 24 (of which one is implicit). 2^24 comes out to 16777216 which is seven digits and part of the eighth. The next (higher) representable integer is 2^24+2^1 or 16777218. 16777217 is NOT representable as a float. The previous (lower) integer is 2^24-2^0 or 16777215. So it is possible to start at 0 and, by adding 1 (2^0), step through all integers up to and including 16777216. Starting at 1677216 it is no longer possible to add 1, one must add 2 (2^1). From 2^25 one must add 2^2 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common format for floating point numbers in C is the IEEE-754 format, described in [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Basic_and_interchange_formats). The [binary32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format) format corresponds to a `float`, and the [binary64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) format corresponds to a `double`.

A `float` has just over 7 decimal digits of precision. Since the answer to your equation has 8 significant digits, the answer cannot be exactly represented as a `float`.

A `double` has almost 16 decimal digits of precision, and therefore does have an exact representation of the answer. Therefore, in general, when you are doing general purpose mathematics, you should be using `doubles`. However, it's important to note that even a `double` may not have enough precision for every application. For example, the national debt of the United States is 18,149,752,816,959.61 which barely fits into a `double`.

Comment: There's also `long double` which often has 80 (or 128) bits and can represent all signed 64b integers exactly: 1b sign, 15b exponent, 1b "flag", 63b fraction.

Comment: @jschultz410 Good point. I hesitate to recommend `long double` since it isn't very well standardized across different systems. Unlike `double` and `float` which are almost always 64 and 32 bits respectively, the `long double` could be 128, 80, or 64 bit depending on the system.